# Writing a regex for git check in Comments

Tags: regex

I have to write a regex so that when ever a developer check in a code in the repository the comments could be verified to maintain a standard.

Below are the requirements:

1. The comment must start with project code which would be one among `RGT`, `UYT` and `WWB`.
2. Contains "`-`" and then a 4 letter change code which is numeric.
3. Followed by a space then a "`|`" symbol and then space again.
4. Finally the change description consists of numbers and alphabets.

Below is the regex I tried

```
[^(RGT|UYT|WWB)-[0-9]{4}\s[|]\s[0-9a-zA-Z\s]$]
```

sample test case

```
UYT-7905 | Changes to implement latest
```

Comment: I think you mean like this `^(RGT|UYT|WWB)-[0-9]{4}\s[|]\s[0-9a-zA-Z\s]+$` https://regex101.com/r/qbuHRP/1 Or if there has to be at least a single char not being a whitespace char for the description `^(RGT|UYT|WWB)-[0-9]{4}\s[|]\s[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z\s]*$`

Comment: Yah it worked Thanks @Thefourthbird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can omit the square brackets, and you have to repeat the last character class 1 or more times to match the description in the example string.

```
^(RGT|UYT|WWB)-[0-9]{4}\s[|]\s[0-9a-zA-Z\s]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qbuHRP/1)

If there should be at least a single char A-Za-z0-9 for the description after matching a single whitespace char (to not match 2 spaces only for the description):

```
^(RGT|UYT|WWB)-[0-9]{4}\s[|]\s[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z\s]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DLNno3/1)

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope below pattern will help:

```
(RGT|UYT|WWB)-[\d]{4}\s\|\s[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/sq1tLa/1